# how child thread can notify parent thread to terminate all the other child thread java

Tags: java, multithreading

my problem is following

a parent thread create 5 child thread and all the child thread start finding result and the one child thread get the result it have to notify the parent thread that it got the result and terminate all the other child thread

Answer (score 2):

That's not a sane way to do it. Just code the child threads to stop doing work that no longer needs to be done. Any time you catch yourself asking "How can I push my code around around from the outside to make it do with I want?", stop and correct yourself. The right question is, "How can I write my code to do what I actually want it to do in the first place so that I don't have to push it around from the outside?"

Comment: If I had my grumpy hat on today I would call this handwaving ... but I haven't, so I wont ;). If OP asked himself *How can I write my code to do what I actually want it to do?* his answer would probably be *I would write it to stop all the other threads when one thread finds the right answer*.

Comment: @Paul But then he hasn't coded the other thread to do what he wants them to do. He's coded them to do work he *doesn't* want them to do and pushed to some other piece of code the task of making the first chunk of code do what he wants. My point is simple -- write all your code to do what you want it to do, then you don't have to worry about figuring out how to make it do what you want it do from someplace else.

Comment: I read the question as OP has got his code doing what he wants it to do. Now he wants advice on how to stop it before it's finished. I.e. How to interrupt them.

Comment: That is the question the OP is asking. And my answer is that he is asking the wrong question. The question he should ask is, "Why are my threads still working even after the job they are doing is finished, such that I need to find some way to interrupt them?" When the solution is found, the job is finished, regardless of who found it. The threads should be coded to stop when they are finished so no external "interrupt" is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Set the children to update a field in the parent if it isn't null. have the children occasionally check if the field is null or not. if it isn't, they should stop.

Does that work?

Comment: but this will increase performance overhead if i will  call the method of parent class to terminate all thread then i think it will work but i don't know how parent thread can terminate all the child thread in java

Comment: +1, although a volatile boolean is a better choice than a null test on an object (boolean variables connote conditions, object variables do not).

Comment: @user1047873 - yes, it will add some microscopic amount of overhead. But the only clean way to terminate a thread is to use a flag. *Do not* use Thread.stop(), it's deprecated for a reason.

Comment: This is just a flawed re-implementation of the interrupted flag.

Answer (score 2):

I feel it would be perfectly acceptable for termination of the other child threads be performed by the child thread. Especially if the child threads are using blocking methods. You just need a parent `stop` method accessable by the children.

Something like:

```
public interface Stopable {
  public void stop ();
}

public class Child
    extends Thread {
  final Stopable parent;
  boolean foundAnswer = false;

  Child ( Stopable parent ) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }

  public void run () {
    try {
      while ( !isInterrupted() ) {
        // Do some work.
        work();

        if ( foundAnswer ) {
          // Stop everyone.
          parent.stop();
        }
      }
    } catch ( InterruptedException ie ) {
      // Just exit when interrupted.
    }
  }

  private void work () throws InterruptedException {
    while ( !foundAnswer ) {
      // Do some work.

      // Should we stop now?
      checkForInterrupt ();
    }
  }

  private void checkForInterrupt () throws InterruptedException {
    if ( isInterrupted() ) {
      throw new InterruptedException();
    }
  }

}

public class Mainthread
    implements Stopable {
  ArrayList<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child> ();

  public void go () {
    // Spawn a number of child threads.
    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      Child newChild = new Child( this );
      children.add( newChild );
      newChild.start();
    }
  }

  public void stop () {
    // Interrupt/kill all child threads.
    for ( Child c : children ) {
      c.interrupt();
    }
  }
}
```